# How can I trigger a mouseover event using a dropdown in D3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am building a line chart using D3.js and I want users to be able to use a drop down menu to highlight values for their Zip Code. I am already doing this with a mouseover event when a user hovers over a line.

I've tried setting mouseover and mouseout events to call an "onmouseover" function as seen here:

```
series.selectAll(".hover")
 .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
   d3.selectAll(".line")
     .style("opacity", 0.82)
     .filter(function(p) { return p.zipcode == d.zipcode; })
     .style("opacity", 1)
     .style("stroke-width", 2)
     .style("stroke", function(d,i) { return color2(i); });
   d3.selectAll(".series text")
     .style("opacity", 0)
     .filter(function(p) { return p.zipcode == d.zipcode; })
     .style("opacity", 1)
     .on("mouseover", onmouseover)
     .on("mouseout", onmouseout);
```

I then also have my "onmouseover" function  that is to be activated by the dropdown:

```
function onmouseover(d,i){
    d3.selectAll(".line")
      .style("opacity", 0.82)
      .filter(function(p) { return p.name == d.name; })
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .style("stroke-width", 2)
      .style("stroke", function(d,i) { return color2(i); })
     d3.selectAll(".series text")
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .filter(function(p) { return p.name == d.name; })
      .style("opacity", 1);}})
```

Which I try to activate when using a dropdown menu:

```
$("#dropdownselect").change(ziphandler)
   function ziphandler(){
   var key = $(this)
          .children(":selected")
          .val();
  onmouseover({id : key});
}
```

The ideal outcome is that a user can hover over a line to see the new style and also highlight a line by selecting their Zip Code in a dropdown menu.

EDIT: The code is here to see in action: http://bl.ocks.org/cminshew/31581ca3e55fbf67862a

Comment: ...and you're saying that the code you have doesn't work? You would need to pass the data to the mouseover function in the format that it expects, i.e. `{name: key}`.

Comment: Correct. It's not working. I've edited the original question with a link to the chart. I apologize if I'm not asking the right question. This is my first real work with D3. I will work on formatting that properly though!

Comment: Well, you hadn't included JQuery, selected the wrong ID for the dropdown, declared the handler function in the wrong scope and used a non-existing attribute to select the line, but apart from that it seems to work: http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/f6f9c5bcffd805441605

Comment: Thank you for that Lars. I appreciate this greatly. I'll be sure to study this closely and avoid those mistakes in the future.

Comment: Great, I'll add this as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

- You didn't include JQuery.
- The ID of the dropdown selector is `zipselected` and not `dropdownselect`.
- The `ziphandler` and `onmouseover` functions are declared in different scopes. In particular, you can't call `onmouseover` from `ziphandler`.
- In your `onmouseover` function, you are referencing a `.name` attribute, which does not exists.

Working demo [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/f6f9c5bcffd805441605).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to call `$(this).onmouseover({id : key});`